# Quotients of varieties by finite group which are also flat maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a ring with an action of a finite group $G$.

Is there a special name for an action that satisfies that $A$ is a projective module over the ring of invariants $A^G$?

More generally is there a special name for an action of a finite group $G$ on a projective variety $X$ which satisfies that the quotient map $X \to X/G$ is flat?

Comment: If the $G$ action is free, then $X\to X/G$ is flat. My  guess is the other direction works too.